# How to solve strict-origin-when-cross-origin and AxiosError {message: 'Network Error',} net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in react js + Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

I am completely new to ReactJs and I am trying to learn it using Laravel and following a tutorial, but I am faced with the below error:

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/signup
>
> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I have tried these videos which shows how to solve the issue, but it doesn't work for me, is there any other way or am I missing something?

Links are below:

- [Fix CORS Policy issue when calling api to another domain service. reactjs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B5WgTiKIOY)
- [React Proxy | Easiest Fix to CORS Errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4yUiQiTvwU)
- Tutorial [link is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHRe5XNP5l8&t=79s)

Answer (score 0):

On your Laravel project:

1. Check if cors.php file exists in config/cors.php location.
2. If the file does not exists please follow https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors
3. On `'allowed_origins' => []`, add the base URL of the react application in the array. Make sure you add the URL of both production and development.

Note: If your both application are running in `localhost`, then cors issue may not occur.

Comment: I am runing the both applicastion in localhost and the 'allowed_origins' => ['*'] measn allow every kind of origins it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by doing two steps

1.I have added the below lines in **.env** file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8000
```

2. and run `php artisan serve` in bakend and run `cd react` `npm run dev`

the below errors are solved as well as

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/signup
>
> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
>
> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code:
> 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}  POST
> http://localhost:8000/api/signup net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED